# Autowiring standalone application with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have an application, but can't get it to run in Eclipse or elsewhere.

Here is my class :

```
package fr.aaa;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Computation {

    public Computation() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml");
        Computation computer = context.getBean(Computation.class);
    }
}
```

and my applicationContext.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">  

<import resource="classpath:spring/persistence.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="fr.aaa.*, com.bbb.*"/> 

<util:properties id="jdbcProps" location="jdbc.properties" />   

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
         <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
         <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [fr.aaa.Computation] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
```

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
fr.aaa.*
```

to

```
fr.aaa
```

Do the same thing for all packages.

The `base-package` attribute is

```
The comma-separated list of packages to scan for annotated components.
```

There are no wildcards involved. You have to use the specific name of the package. Spring will take care of scanning sub packages.